# Designer serialization of custom structure

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've a custom structure:

```
Public Structure myStruct
   Public Sub New(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal Col As Integer)
      X = row : Y = Col
   End Sub
   Property X() As Integer
   Property Y() As Integer
end Structure
```

That I'm using as a Property in a UserControl:

```
Public Class myUC
   inherits UserControl

   Property myProp1 As String = "test"
   Property MyProp2 As myStruct = New myStruct(1, 2)
End Class
```

If I put this UserControl on a Form the Windows Form Designer will create a piece of code in the `InitializeComponent` method that looks like this:

```
'
'MyUC1
'
Me.MyUC1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(205, 187)
Me.MyUC1.myProp1 = "test"

Me.MyUC1.MyProp2 = CType(resources.GetObject("MyUC1.MyProp2"), WindowsApp11.myStruct)
Me.MyUC1.Name = "MyUC1"
Me.MyUC1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(150, 150)
Me.MyUC1.TabIndex = 0
```

But I would like to have myStruct serialized like the `System.Drawing.Point` structure. Thus the resulting Designer code should be

```
'
'MyUC1
'
Me.MyUC1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(205, 187)
Me.MyUC1.myProp1 = "test"
Me.MyUC1.MyProp2 = new WindowsApp11.myStruct(1,2)
Me.MyUC1.Name = "MyUC1"
Me.MyUC1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(150, 150)
Me.MyUC1.TabIndex = 0
```

Has anyone an idea how to tell the Windows Form Designer how to serialize the custom structure. I was thinking of something like the  Serialization.IXmlSerializable  interface, but for Design-Time.

I've tried to find something using Google, but I seem to use the wrong search expressions.

Thx

Comment: You need to implement a type converter and override a few methods. You will find an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060816/3110834).

Comment: And here is [source code of `PointConverter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/PointConverter.cs,0e3a4309646c3111).  The key methods for this feature are `GetCreateInstanceSupported` and `CreateInstance`.

Comment: I reopen as it's a VB question.

Comment: Thank you for this. This was exactly the solution I was looking for! It works like a charm!

Comment: No problem, I posted a VB answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which can convert your object to [`InstanceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then the designer generate the serialized code using the constructor of your struct.

To do so you need to derive from `TypeConverter` or one of classes which derive from `TypeConverter`, like [`ExpandableObjectConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then override a few methods.

**Example**

1. Create a VB.NET Windows Forms Application. (The application project)
2. Create a VB.NET Control Library Application. (The control project)
3. Add MyPoint.vb and paste the following code inside it to add `MyPoint` structure and `MyPointConverter` class:

   ```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization
    Imports System.Globalization

    <TypeConverter(GetType(MyPointConverter))>
    Public Structure MyPoint
        Public Property X As Integer
        Public Property Y As Integer
        Public Sub New(X As Integer, Y As Integer)
            Me.X = X
            Me.Y = Y
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Public Class MyPointConverter
        Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter
        Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType As Type) As Boolean
            If destinationType = GetType(InstanceDescriptor) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType)
        End Function
        Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As CultureInfo, value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object
            If destinationType = GetType(InstanceDescriptor) Then
                Dim ci = GetType(MyPoint).GetConstructor(New Type() {GetType(Integer), GetType(Integer)})
                MessageBox.Show(value.ToString())
                Dim i = DirectCast(value, MyPoint)
                Return New InstanceDescriptor(ci, New Object() {i.X, i.Y})
            End If
            Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
        End Function
        Public Overrides Function GetCreateInstanceSupported(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function
        Public Overrides Function CreateInstance(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, propertyValues As IDictionary) As Object
            If (propertyValues Is Nothing) Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(propertyValues))
            End If
            Dim X = DirectCast(propertyValues(NameOf(MyPoint.X)), Integer)
            Dim Y = DirectCast(propertyValues(NameOf(MyPoint.Y)), Integer)
            Return New MyPoint(X, Y)
        End Function
    End Class
   ```
4. Open UserControl1.vb and paste the following code to add `MyPoint` property:

   ```
    Public Class UserControl1
        Public Property MyPoint As MyPoint
    End Class
   ```
5. Close all designers and rebuild the solution.
6. Open the first project (application project) and open Form1 in design mode and from toolbox, drop an instance of UserControl1, change `MyPoint` property and save changes.
7. see the InitializeComponent method and you see:

   ```
    'UserControl11
    '
    Me.UserControl11.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(65, 65)
    Me.UserControl11.MyPoint = New WindowsControlLibrary1.MyPoint(1, 2)
    Me.UserControl11.Name = "UserControl11"
    Me.UserControl11.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(150, 150)
    Me.UserControl11.TabIndex = 2
   ```

**Tip**

1. Put the control in a different project than the application project to prevent some unexpected designer crash or exceptions in serialziation.
2. To clean windows forms designer project assemblies, you need to delete subforlders of `ProjectAssemblies` folder which is located in `%userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\` under one of the folders depending to your visual studio version and edition. For me, they are here:

   ```
    C:\Users\rag\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_dc21d183\ProjectAssemblies
   ```
3. If you need to debug design time, follow the steps explained here: [How to debug WinForms designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347549/3110834).